# Авторизация в Яндекс

Tags: python

Авторизация в яндекс не проходит

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-en,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',

    'Connection': 'keep-close'
}
session = requests.session()
url = 'https://passport.yandex.ru/passport?mode=auth&retpath=https://yandex.ru'
data = {'login': '********', 'passwd': '********'}
r = session.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Яндекс API OAuth для моего сервиса не подходит.
подскажите, что не так.

Comment: Во-первых, почему вы решили, что здесь что-то не так? Во-вторых, почему вы решили, что этот код вообще должен работать? Как и почему вы его написали именно таким? В-третьих, это скорее всего нарушает какие-нибудь правила Яндекса, что снижает вероятность получения помощи здесь

Comment: Чем вам не угодил Яндекс API? Он как раз для этого и придуман

Comment: Судя по коду вы не через тот URL пытаетесь авторизоваться. Попробуйте тот, что из [документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/oauth/doc/dg/reference/web-client-docpage/).